# for loop in javascript is skipping else if condition half the time

Tags: javascript

I'm was just fiddling around with javascript and I wrote function using Math.random that I thought would return a coin-flip. Then I was curious so I ran it through a loop to test how often it flips true/false. I found out my loop is skipping about half of the else if conditions, and was able to verify this by catching them in the errors var. So, why is it doing this?

```
var truths = 0;
var alternativetruths = 0;
var errors = 0;

function game() {
  var score = Math.random()*10;
  return score>5;
}

for(i=0;i<999999;i++) {
  if (game() === true) {
    truths++
  } else if (game() === false) {
    alternativetruths++
  } else {
    errors++
  }
}
console.log("truths:",truths,"alternativetruths:",alternativetruths,"errors:",errors)
```

truths: 500393 alternativetruths: 249580 errors: 250026

Comment: Basicly what you do is after your coinflip, if the result is `false`, you flip another coin and if that one gives `true`, you end up in the last `else` case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're calling `game` **twice**, and thus getting two different random flags.

The minimal change is to remember the number:

```
for(i=0;i<999999;i++) {
  var flag = game();
  if (flag === true) {
    truths++
  } else if (flag === false) {
    alternativetruths++
  } else {
    errors++
  }
}
```

But a couple of other notes:

- If `flag` is a boolean (and it is, it's the result of the `>` operator), then `if (flag === true)` is pointless. Just use `if (flag)`. The result of the `===` operator is a boolean too, so if you don't trust them to be true or false, where do you stop? :-) `if ((flag === true) === true)`?
- Separately, `if (flag === false)` should just be `if (!flag)`.
- If `flag` is a boolean (and it is), then if you have `if (flag)`, having `else if (!flag)` and then `else` doesn't make any sense. There is no way you'll reach that final `else`. Just `if (flag) { } else { }` is all you need.
- **But**, `game` isn't fair, it has a ***very slight*** bias toward returning `false`. Remember, the range returned by `Math.random() * 10` is `0` to just under 10, so checking for `> 5` means you're skipping the midpoint. Because you're dealing with very small fractional numbers, you don't notice the bias, but it's there; it would be more obvious if you rounded to whole numbers, at which point it would be roughly 40%/60% true/false. You want `>= 5` for fair results.
- `game` can rather moer succinctly be written: `return Math.random() >= 0.5;`.
- Because you're not declaring `i`, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Remember to declare your variables.

Re `>` vs. `>=`, here's an example where I've rounded to whole numbers to make the effect clearer:

```js
for (var n = 0; n < 4; ++n) {
  setTimeout(test.bind(null, n, true), 200 * n);
  setTimeout(test.bind(null, n, false), 200 * n + 100);
}
function test(num, gte) {
  var truths = 0;
  var alternativetruths = 0;
  var errors = 0;

  function game() {
    var score = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    return gte ? score >= 5 : score > 5;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
    var flag = game();
    if (flag) {
      truths++;
    } else {
      alternativetruths++;
    }
  }
  showStats(num, gte, truths, alternativetruths);
}
function showStats(num, gte, truths, alternativetruths) {
  var total = truths + alternativetruths; // Should be 999999 of course
  var truthsPercent = (truths * 100) / total;
  var altPercent = (alternativetruths * 100) / total;
  console.log(num, gte ? ">=" : ">", "truths:", truths, "alternativetruths:", alternativetruths, "(" + truthsPercent.toFixed(2) + "% vs. " + altPercent.toFixed(2) + "%)");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @Pointy: Heh, you were ~30s ahead of me. Amazing similarly though.

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this as the answer because you put so much effort into improving my code.
However, I don't get different results with >= 5, vs > 5. I tried both and they both return 50/50 I thought about this and it's actually what I would expect. Can you weigh in on this and show me why I might be wrong?

Comment: @kidconcept: The effect is ***very very small*** (not the 40%/60% I originally said, I'd missed that you weren't rounding to whole numbers), but it's there. I've corrected the text, explained it more, and added an example.

Answer (score 9):

Your code calls `game()` **twice**. If the first call *isn't* `true`, then the second might or might not be `true`.

Just call `game()` once and assign the result to a variable. Don't make explicit comparisons to `true` and `false`; `if` statements work off boolean values, and your function already returns one of those.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
  var result = game();
  if (result)
    truths++;
  else
    alternativetruths++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign game to a var before test for its value. Otherwise, everytime yout check the value with game() you will check a new value. So it can be false at the first check and true at the second and for this reason increment your errors.
Try this:

```
for(i=0;i<999999;i++) {
  let gameResult = game();
  if (gameResult === true) {
    truths++
  } else if (gameResult === false) {
    alternativetruths++
  } else {
    errors++
  }
}
```